# Possible incongruence in Sympy when assuming positive numbers

Tags: python, sympy

Using Sympy package version 1.0 on Python 2.7.11 I found what (to me) is an incongruence. This is the code I'm using:

```
import sympy as sy
from sympy.stats import Normal, density
from sympy.assumptions import assuming, Q, ask

sy.init_printing()

a = sy.symbols('a', real=True)
with assuming(Q.positive(a)): 
    print ask(Q.positive(a))
    N = Normal('N', 0, a)
```

What I got is

```
True
```

from the first print as expected but an exception when creating the Normal object

```
ValueError: Standard deviation must be positive
```

Can anyone, please, explain if it is intended to be like this and why? Thanks!

PS: I'm aware that I could declare the symbols to be positive

Comment: Your example could be simplified further; b and c can be dropped; calling Normal('N', 0, a) will throw the same error, for the reason explained by Francesco Bonazzi. The condition that Normal requires is std > 0, and the boolean value of that is returned as None.

Comment: @soup: thanks I edited the question so the code looks simpler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is simple: there are two assumptions systems in SymPy, called the old-style and new-style assumptions. They don't interact quite well, yet.

The old-style assumptions define predicates on symbols, e.g.

```
x = Symbol("x", positive=True)
```

deduction is then performed on generic expressions with methods such as `.is_positive`

```
>>> x.is_positive
True
```

The latest version of SymPy has linked the old-style assumptions to the new-style ones, so you can now query

```
>>> ask(Q.positive(x))
True
```

Older versions of SymPy would return `None`, as the two assumptions systems were not linked at all.

The problem is that this relation is **not yet** reciprocal: the old-style assumptions system is not aware of assumptions defined with the new-style assumptions system. You can verify it yourself:

```
>>> with assuming(Q.positive(y)):
...    print y.is_positive    
None
```

The random variable *Normal* requires the standard deviation parameter to be positive, verification is done with the old-style assumptions. Therefore your case fails.

Note that the positivity condition on the standard deviation is likely to get relaxed to a non-negativity condition in the next SymPy version (that is, allow the positivity-indefinite case to be accepted).

Comment: Indeed, a [recent commit](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/commit/02b9dec4ebf5f8a36f538306a24a90ba41bd984f) changes `_check_value` so that it raises ValueError when `condition == False`, not when `condition != True`.